# Getting bootstrap accordion in views to aggregate based on user name?

Tags: views

I would like to have an accordion with the users name as the title. The users name should appear once with the latest 3 articles for each user/author inside the accordion container.

```
John
 * Monday Post
 * Tuesday Post
Jake
 * Monday Post
```

I've got Drupal 7 & views_bootstrap. The user profile is customised to have first and last names.

I can get a similar result starting from content or user objects and creating a relationship.

With one author it looks like the following

[image]

with an accordion for each content item.

Logically it is an 'aggregate' although I understand that in sql there are limitations in using group by and presenting columns that aren't in the group by. The views UI seems to represent this, with group by on all columns. Distinct doesn't do it. So how?

The experimental view is

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'authors';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'Authors';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Research Team';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'views_bootstrap_accordion_plugin_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['title_field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: User: Content authored */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['required'] = TRUE;
/* Field: User: First name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_first_name']['id'] = 'field_first_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_first_name']['table'] = 'field_data_field_first_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_first_name']['field'] = 'field_first_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_first_name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_first_name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_first_name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_first_name']['settings'] = array(
  'field_formatter_class' => '',
 );
 /* Field: User: Last name */
 $handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_last_name']['id'] = 'field_last_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_last_name']['table'] = 'field_data_field_last_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_last_name']['field'] = 'field_last_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_last_name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_last_name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_last_name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_last_name']['settings'] = array(
  'field_formatter_class' => '',
);
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['text'] = '[field_first_name] [field_last_name] ';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: User: Created date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: User: Active */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_1']['id'] = 'status_1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_1']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_1']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_1']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_1']['value'] = '1';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
 'blog' => 'blog',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'authors';

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'views_bootstrap_accordion_plugin_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['title_field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['inline'] = array(
   'field_first_name' => 'field_first_name',
   'field_last_name' => 'field_last_name',
   'name' => 'name',
);
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [views nested accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_nested_accordion) module worked

[image]